# "Field is never used" although its (field's) constructor runs

Tags: c++, clion

```
class SdlManager
{
public:
    SdlManager();
    ~SdlManager();
};

class Application
{
    SdlManager sdlManager;
    Screen screen;
    EventHandler eventHandler;

    bool running = true;
    int fps = Fps;

    void Draw();

public:
    Application();
    void Run();
    void Stop();

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Application app;
    app.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

Hi. I'm toying with SDL using Clion and I noticed this warning which seems strange: it complains that the field sdlManager is never used, but I'm sure (even using breakpoints) that the program runs sdlManager's constructor when I instantiate an Application object inside main.

What should I do? Is it a Clion's (or whatever plugin it uses) bug?

Comment: The warning doesn't say that it isn't initialized. It is. The warning states, that it isn't **used** after being initialized.

Comment: Does the constructor actually _do_ something that makes construction useful on its own without a following use of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

`sdlManager` is constructed, but it's never used after that. That's why you're getthing the warning.

Once you'll add methods to it, and start using them, the warning will go away.

The point of that warning is to signal code that isn't used anywhere in the code, either someone forgot to use it, or it needs to be removed (after some refactoring or something).

Comment: `SdlManager` might be some RAII object though, so legit. (SDL has code to initialize and shutdown its "systems").

Comment: True, but most of the time you'll still want to do something with it, right?

Comment: There is a tradeoff between too many warnings because of legit RAII object, and missing not used fields (and unfortunately they might also be RAII objects (as `std::string`)). There is still attribute `[[maybe_unused]]` which might solve that.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried with [[maybe_unused]] but then I got a compiler warning telling me that it (the compiler it seems) ignored the attribute (maybe_unused)

Comment: @user3621272 That attribute is available in C++17, you need to change the c++ version you're using.

Comment: @ShadowMitia I'm using C++20, set up through cmake: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20). `warning: 'maybe_unused' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]`

Comment: @Jarod42 On the other hand, it doesn't really make sense to have a member object just for its existence. If some initialization and/or shutdown has to be done, it's probably needed globally, not per instance. And if it's needed per instance, it's needed because you somehow interact with that "system", which would fix that warning.

Comment: Can be done in Singleton, or RAII objects might use some shared counter. In OP's case, `class Application` seems to be the "system".